# Error correction code capability

Tags: reed-solomon, forwarderrorcorrection

Is it possible to achieve 25%+ error correction capability when output cannot be bigger than 175% of input?
I was looking for Reed-Solomon code. With 255 output symbols, I can have 145 input symbols. (145 * 1.75 < 255)

That means (110/2)/255 * 100% = 21.5%

Is there any method or other error correction code to achieve 25%+?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

The output being 175% of the input means the input is 57% of the whole data. A RS code, as you know, needs 50% space for 25% error correcting capability, that won't fit in.
And, as long as you want something comparable to what a RS code can do, *nothing is better* in terms of used space. RS codes are optimal according to the [singleton bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_bound).

The only chance to get better than that is to use a unreliable scheme that sometimes corrects more than RS, but other times fails where RS would have worked.